# Change mixed data types in power query to decimal- Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a column in a table which looks like below

[image]

There was strings in this column which gave me errors when I changed type to decimal (type number) which I had replaced with 0.0 using `Replace Errors`.

I had then pivoted the column post which the column looks like below:

[image]

However when I close and apply the changes, this turns the decimals to whole numbers so the data view looks like below:

[image]

how to fix this issue, I want to retain the decimals (I have already tried changing the types to decimal and fixed decimal but both didnt work).

**Note** : I have also found [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/convert-calclulated-column-datatype-text-to-decimal-number/td-p/441971) link which suggests that we can convert the format in modelling tab and change one by one columns to decimals , however I am looking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: in power query the type is decimal right? what happens when you edit the type in the Modelling tab?

Comment: @Datanovice umm if I remember I had changed the type it manually following [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/convert-calclulated-column-datatype-text-to-decimal-number/td-p/441971) but wasnt happy particularly doing so

Comment: hmm, I just tried to reproduce your error and it comes out as a decimal number column with no issues, my modelling tab automatically updated too. If that fails maybe a DAX expression with a switch statement to handle the mixed data types ?  I asked something similair [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617128/dax-to-test-for-whole-number)

Comment: @Datanovice I see , may be version issues.. powerbi keeps updating itself so might have been fixed now. BDW thanks for trying to reproduce :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it works if you replace the dots for commas.

Comment: can you explain please ? replace dots where? thanks

Comment: In your column:
10.2 | 20.2 | 30.2 -> 10,2 | 20,2 | 30,2

Comment: I see, I will try, though I need the `.` for other dependant calculations