# DAX to Test for Whole Number

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Actuals column like so:

```
ID | Airport
------------
A  | 98.4
B  | 98.0
C  | 95.3
```

I'm attempting to format the numbers above into percentages for a front-end report. I have this written in a switch statement - for ease I'll just write the logic as an IF boolean.

```
example_measure = 
VAR Nums = SELECTEDVALUES(Table[Actuals])
VAR FormatNums = IF(DIVIDE(ROUND(nums,1), nums) = 1,
                              format(nums,"0%"),format(nums,"0.0%")
-
RETURN 
FormatNums
```

no matter what I do this *always* returns a number with a floating point value of `1f`

so in my raw data of 98.0 I'm expecting the format to return `"98%"` rather than `"98.0%"`

the measures are used on individual cards, and are filtered so they can only ever show one value or blank, meaning they will only ever display one value on their own.

I've toyed with using `if(nums = int(nums)` which should evaluate to true for `98.0` but it I always get false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler way - just use built-in formatting codes:

```
Formatted Actuals = 
  VAR x = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Actuals])
  RETURN
  FORMAT(x, "General Number") & "%"
```

Result:

[image]

Built-in style "General Number" handles your situation correctly, you just need to add % symbol to the formatted string. No need to test for whole numbers.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a column/measure into percentage, you can simply divide the column by 100 and then format it as a percentage. Use the following steps:

1. Create a new column/measure: `Perc_value = Table[Actuals]/100`
2. Then go into the modelling tab, select the created column/measure and format it as a % and limit the number of decimal places to 0

This should give the view you are looking for. Hope this helps.

Edit:

You can use the below formula to achieve the desired result:

```
Column4 = IF('Table'[Column2]-ROUND('Table'[Column2],0)=0,FORMAT('Table'[Column2]/100,"0%"),FORMAT('Table'[Column2]/100,"0.0%"))
```

Replace Column2 withyour field and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for this - unfortunately it doesn't help, I have no issue with formatting my number as a percent, that's quite simple. What I'm trying to do is add a custom measure to visually present my percent, that is, if it's `99.0` i want it to show `99%` if it's `99.1` then i want `99.1%` curently I'm _only_ getting `99.0%`

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Added an edit to get what you are looking for. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: getting an error `A single value for column 'Actual' in table 'Actuals' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count,` in my original measure I had selected my column with `selectedvalues` does that make a difference? I'm creating a measure

Comment: Are you creating a column or measure? You should be creating a column from the looks of it

Comment: Why do you need the selected values? Since you have mentioned it should be a maximum of one value, wouldn't just the filter work?

Comment: I'm creating a measure to save redundancy - I'm still quite new to DAX, but from my understanding of the method - I need to select a value by a filter context that is by `ID` in my Table above, wthen has a further filter by date (which i haven't included)

Comment: In that case, you can modify your measure to something like VAR Nums = Sum(SELECTEDVALUES(Table[Actuals]))...This should resolve your issue